# how provide value from text file to yaml file?

Tags: yaml

I am using YAML file to read/write data from the s3 bucket, i have mentioned the AWS access key and secret key inside the YAML file itself.
but now I want to put aws_secret_key in another txt file, and read the secret key from the text file.

How can we configure the YAML file to read the aws_secret_ key from another file?

Please help me.

Thanks & Regards,
Prasad

Comment: i am using the linux system.

Comment: YAML is data. You cannot use YAML to read/write anything because it is not runnable. You *can* use a tool that loads YAML and acts on its content, which is probably what you're doing, but you need to tell us *which* tool that is. YAML itself cannot refer to external files, but tools using YAML might provide ways to do this.